# pyspark how to sum and produce top 10 using pyspark

Tags: dictionary, pyspark

I have a csv file with two fields, a key and a value:

```
{1Y4dZ123eAMGooBmVzBLUWEZ2JfCCUY91},8.530366
{1YdZ123433MGooBmVzBLUWEZ1234CUY91},8.530366
{1YdZ2344AMGooBmVzBLUWE123JfCCUY91},8.530366
{1YdECDNthiMGooBmVzBLUWEZ2JfCCUY91},8.530366
{1YdZDNHqeAMGooBmVzBLUWEZ2JfCCUY91},8.530366
{1YdZDNHqeAMGooBDJTdBLUWEZ2JfCCUY91},8.530366
{1YdZDNHqeAMGooBmVzBLUWEZ2JfCCUY91},8.530366
{1YdZ123qeAMGooBmVzBLUWEZ2JfCCUY91},8.530366
{1YdZDNHqeAMGooBmVzBLUWEZ2JfCCUY91},8.530366
{1YdZDNHqeAMGooBm123LUWEZ2JfCCUY91},8.530366
{17RJgv5ujkFerSd48Akdd2GneUAW47nphQ},20.0
{17RJgv5ujkFerSd48Akdd2GneUAW47nphQ},20.0
{17RJgv5ujkFerSd48Akdd2GneUAW47nphQ},20.0
{13uZ6tSr5oh1ui9Hd1tEqJKo2AHhJ6JdFS},0.03895804
```

What I'm trying to do is sum up the second column and group by the first column, then derive the top 10 keys with the highest values.

Below is the code I've tried using but I get a 'tuple index out of range' error:

````
import re
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)


voutFile = sc.textFile("input/voutfiltered.csv")

features=voutFile.map(lambda l:
    (l.split(',')[0],float(l.split(',')[1])))

top10 = features.takeOrdered(10, key = lambda x: -x[2])
for record in top10:
    print("{}: {};{}".format(record[0],record[1],record[2]))```
````

Comment: your RDD elements are two-item tuples, most likely you need to adjust x[2] to x[1] --> `top10 = features.takeOrdered(10, key = lambda x: -x[1])` and remove record[2] in print function.

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why you're not using the DataFrame API? It's much more flexible, convenient and faster than the RDD API.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/path/to/your/file.csv/")

(df.groupBy(f.col("key_col"))
   .agg(f.count(f.col("value_col")).alias("count_value_col"))
   .sort(col("count_value_col").desc())
   .limit(10)
   .show())
```